# Alertifyjs alerts shown to the person who triggered it

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, alertifyjs

As a disclaimer, I'm new to nodejs and express framework in general so please bear with me while I'm still trying to learn. 
I'm using [alertifyjs library](http://alertifyjs.com/) to show notifications for various alerts to a user. Now, the problem is that the notifications are showing for everyone who is on the site. I get why this is happening and it makes sense. How do I go about making it so a specific alert only shows for the person that triggered it? What exactly do I use to make this happen? Cookies?
Thank you for your help and let me know if you need any more information.

Here's a code example...

```
//client code
socket.on('word length', function(data) {
  alertify.error('Check word length!');
});


//server code
if (word.length > 50 || word.length <= 1) { // check word length:
  io.sockets.emit('word length', word);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. For instance, how would your user trigger it?

Comment: Added a code example of how I'm making this happen. I'm using sockets to trigger alertify notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with `alertify` but more to do with how `socket.io` works. The [io.socket.emit](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit) call will broadcast a message to *all* connected sockets.

You want to call `emit` on the client socket only

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    io.socket.emit('message', 'to everyone');
    socket.emit('message', 'to this client only');
});
```

Comment: Wow that was too easy. Thank you so much for your help.